# How do i print my barcode output to a file?

Tags: python, barcode

I have set up a raspberry Pi with a USB barcode scanner for a little project. It works with my generated barcodes, it prints the output of the scanned code in the terminal. I really want to save this input to a txt file that doesn't overwrite itself. I have tried changing all the functions and i just cant get it to work. I'm just a novice in Python and i have been stuck on this for a long time now and i have looked all over the internet. If you can just point me to the specific place in code i need to change in order to print the output out i would be very appreciative.

Source: [Instructables](https://www.instructables.com/id/USB-Barcode-Scanner-Raspberry-Pi/)

## !/usr/bin/python

```
    import sys
    import requests
    import json

    api_key = "" #https://upcdatabase.org/

    def barcode_reader():
        hid = {4: 'a', 5: 'b', 6: 'c', 7: 'd', 8: 'e', 9: 'f', 10: 'g', 11: 'h', 12: 'i', 13: 'j', 14: 'k', 15: 'l', 16: 'm',
              17: 'n', 18: 'o', 19: 'p', 20: 'q', 21: 'r', 22: 's', 23: 't', 24: 'u', 25: 'v', 26: 'w', 27: 'x', 28: 'y',
              29: 'z', 30: '1', 31: '2', 32: '3', 33: '4', 34: '5', 35: '6', 36: '7', 37: '8', 38: '9', 39: '0', 44: ' ',
              45: '-', 46: '=', 47: '[', 48: ']', 49: '\\', 51: ';', 52: '\'', 53: '~', 54: ',', 55: '.', 56: '/'}

        hid2 = {4: 'A', 5: 'B', 6: 'C', 7: 'D', 8: 'E', 9: 'F', 10: 'G', 11: 'H', 12: 'I', 13: 'J', 14: 'K', 15: 'L', 16: 'M',
               17: 'N', 18: 'O', 19: 'P', 20: 'Q', 21: 'R', 22: 'S', 23: 'T', 24: 'U', 25: 'V', 26: 'W', 27: 'X', 28: 'Y',
               29: 'Z', 30: '!', 31: '@', 32: '#', 33: '$', 34: '%', 35: '^', 36: '&', 37: '*', 38: '(', 39: ')', 44: ' ',
               45: '_', 46: '+', 47: '{', 48: '}', 49: '|', 51: ':', 52: '"', 53: '~', 54: '<', 55: '>', 56: '?'}

        fp = open('/dev/hidraw0', 'rb')

        ss = ""
        shift = False

        done = False

        while not done:

             ## Get the character from the HID
             buffer = fp.read(8)
             for c in buffer:
                if ord(c) > 0:

                  ##  40 is carriage return which signifies
                  ##  we are done looking for characters
                   if int(ord(c)) == 40:
                      done = True
                      break;

                  ##  If we are shifted then we have to
                  ##  use the hid2 characters.
                if shift:

                   ## If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                    shift = True

                   ## if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                      else:
                          ss += hid2[int(ord(c))]
                          shift = False

            ##  If we are not shifted then use
            ##  the hid characters

                else:

                    ## If it is a '2' then it is the shift key
                    if int(ord(c)) == 2:
                       shift = True

                    ## if not a 2 then lookup the mapping
                    else:
                        ss += hid[int(ord(c))]
        return ss


    def UPC_lookup(api_key,upc):
        '''V3 API'''

        url = "https://api.upcdatabase.org/product/%s/%s" % (upc, api_key)

        headers = {
        'cache-control': "no-cache",
        }

        response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

        print("-----" * 5)
        print(upc)
        print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
        print("-----" * 5 + "\n")

    if __name__ == '__main__':
        try:
           while True:
               UPC_lookup(api_key,barcode_reader())
        except KeyboardInterrupt:
            pass
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is already printing to the console it means it's coming from this part of the code:

```
print("-----" * 5)
print(upc)
print(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
print("-----" * 5 + "\n")
```

In order to save it to a file you can use the following:

```
with open('FILENAME.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write('CONTENT THAT YOU WANT TO WRITE!\n')
```

Or in your particular case:

```
with open('FILENAME.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write("-----" * 5)
    file.write(upc)
    file.write(json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2))
    file.write("-----" * 5 + "\n")
```

Comment: Thankyou for your time, i just tried this but it just generates an empty .txt file in my trashcan. I am very confused about this.

Comment: I just found out that it even prints the barcodecode it scans to whatever i have opened for example(texteditor,input fields) so basically the whole code doesnt work i think?

Comment: try to understand what is the content of upc and json.dumps(response.json(), indent=2) by removing those print()'s and add back again. And check if it contains what you are searching for. If so this is what you want to write into the file. If the file is empty is because most probably upc and response.json are empty